# Set Network Interface Metric

Tags: linux, networking, archlinux

What is the proper way to set network interface metrics these days?

I'm looking for command line ways for doing this. I'm currently using Arch Linux, but a distro-agnostic method would be preferred.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 metric 1
SIOCSIFMETRIC: Operation not supported
```

Comment: I have a very similar question about ubuntu 14.04 here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/929524/can-i-adjust-metrics-on-my-two-network-interfaces

Comment: Also similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413031/21203 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245208/21203 .

Answer (score 23):

As stated in **man ifconfig**, metric is not a supported option for the **ifconfig** command on Linux systems, because when the **ifconfig** command is processed it doesn't create a routing table entry.

```
   metric N
          This parameter sets the interface metric. It is not available under GNU/Linux.
```

To answer your question, you'd have to use the **route** command, to add the route with the desired metric and delete the old entry. For example:

```
sudo route add -net default gw 10.10.0.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev wlan0 metric 1
sudo route del -net default gw 10.10.0.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev wlan0 metric 0
```

Comment: is there some way to change the metric without specifying the gateway? I saw that gateways are not detectable (we cant find the gw ip with a command), but the gw may be set automatically as soon a new interface is activated; so, with the metric already specified, I could prefer wifi over ethernet; but I cant be sure of the wifi gateway, neither ethernet one.